# PHP - Date returning the wrong value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little bit of code and it doesn't seem to be working correctly.

I'm trying to put it into the correct format for my database. I'm doing the following:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('24/05/2011'));
```

But every time I echo it, it returns:

```
1970-01-01 10:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but try this:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('24/05/2011 00:00:00'));
```

After testing it shows this works:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("24-5-2011"));
```

Answer (score 3):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats
>   are disambiguated by looking at the
>   separator between the various
>   components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is
>   assumed; whereas if the separator is a
>   dash (-) or a dot (.), then the
>   European d-m-y format is assumed.

From the docmentation of [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

This should work

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('05/24/2011'));
```

Comment: Interesting, I've never taken the time to find out how that works before. Is that from PHP.net's documentation?

Comment: If you examine the link, you will indeed find it's the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It means that your `strtotime` function is failing to parse that date. When it fails, it returns `false` which `date` reads as 0, which is the UNIX epoch. As Programmer XR suggested, you may need to switch your format a bit - if what he said doesn't work, try converting the `datetime` into this format:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2011-05-24 00:00:00'));
```

- [strtotime documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). Includes a link to accepted date formats.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's not date() but strtotime(). 
Next, strtotime() is not a magic wand, reading your mind and understands whatever format.
It's just a function, accepting certain arguments.
So, if it returns wrong value - check input parameters and read manual to see if they are correct.

Third, you don't need such complicated function anyway. All you need is a few string operations:

```
list($d,$m,$y) = explode("/",$date);
$date = "$y-$m-$d";
```

Understanding string operations is most important thing in using PHP.